# Will I improve by climbing 10 flights of stairs every day?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises

I started climbing 10 flights of stairs every day. At the end, I'm breathing heavily and by heart is beating rapidly. My calves are hurting a bit...

Will I definitely improve, even though this only takes around 5 minutes a day?

Comment: Yes. Well, you're supposed to. Your body will adapt to those 10 flights ad eventually (length of time different for everyone) it will be easy.

Comment: Think positive, you will definitely do better and the next time you will be ready for another set of stairs after you climb this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking if you will improve in terms of ability to climb stairs, the answer is almost definitely yes.

I myself used to climb up my apartment building everyday, and found that after even a couple days my legs didn't burn as much and I was less out of breath at the top. Your body adapts fast to the work you give it regularly, so don't be surprised if after a couple weeks you find it easy.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what you are trying to improve, I guess you are talking about overall fitness. The answer is quite simple:

Yes, doing anything is better than nothing, so you definitely will improve. If you have more ambitious goals, eg losing weight or gaining muscle you might want to check out some other exercises.
You should be careful however if you are heavily overweight as climbing a lot of stairs might injure your joints.